# Pre-built circuits for a predicted port

Tags: circuit, source-code

According to the Tor documents, Tor builds 2 circuits for each predicted port. I checked the source code to find out how it can understand that it has already built one or two circuit for a predicted port. I checked the functions:

- `circuit_predict_and_launch_new`
- `circuit_all_predicted_ports_handled`
- `circuit_get_unhandled_ports`

I could not understand its process for this issue, I mean there is no counter that shows the number of circuits built for a port. For example, 2 circuits have been built for port 80.

Comment: I could find it in here  #define MIN_CIRCUITS_HANDLING_STREAM   2

Comment: Can you please rephrase this to actually be a question? Always make sure your post has an actual question in it somewhere. Also, if you want to answer your own question please use the answers feature instead of a comment (you should have enough repo to answer your own question if I'm not mistaken). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Sam, Actually I wanted to know how Tor controls the number of circuits built for each port (Tor builds 2 circuits for recently seen ports). When I checked the source code and saw this function "ircuit_predict_and_launch_new", I could not find any clue about this issue, but I found that this function "circuit_all_predicted_ports_handled" return true when there are 2 circuits for each recently seen port.